# Issue with Imapclient connecting via TLS to outlook server using oauth and mailkit nuget package

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, tls1.2, mailkit

I created an application to read an outlook mail inbox folder using oauth2 and mailkit nuget package, but while connecting to the server an exception is thrown saying 'The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.'

Followed the steps of registering the application in Azure and I have the tenantid,clientid and secret and before connecting to the outlook server I am receiving the token as well, but unable to connect to the server.

I am using Mailkit package for reading the mailbox and below is my code snippet for connecting to the server

```
               var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(mailid, accessToken);
                
               await client.ConnectAsync(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

host - outlook.ofice365.com and port - 993
```

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful. Thanks

Tried to change the SecureSocketOptions to Auto but that also resulted in exception saying 'An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.'

client.ConnectAsync(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

Comment: Is the nuget package recent?  Old nuget packages may not work with OAUTH2.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: Yes..the nuget package is latest 4.1.0

Comment: The error you got is a time out due to connection not completing. TLS is sent before the Request is sent.  The error is a general error indicating the connection did not complete.  Usually it means the TLS certificate is bad, but it could mean the authentication is failing. or the FROM address of the email is not matching the email account.  This error is not easy to fixed because it can occur for lots of reasons.  Using Powershell to debug may help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/authentication/automatic-authentication-fails

Comment: There is no issues with the email account.

Comment: You used the same setting with PS as you did with c#?  This means that the certificate is loaded properly.  Otherwise, you would need to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/encryption-office-365-tls-certificates-changes?view=o365-worldwide.  Power shell may be trying multiple different connection method (SMTP and OAUTH2).  See (read carefully) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-guidance

Comment: All the settings are fine and I also used the correct scope as I can receive the token

Comment: You are making two HTTP Requests.  1) Get the token. 2) Perform your query.  The first is working.  Second is failing.  TLS is used for both requests. So error is misleading.  TLS is working since the first request is successful.  Which means the server is refusing the second connection and you are getting a timeout. Often in c# when a connection fails you get a TLS error when the error just means the connection did not complete. The are multiple authentication.  PS is trying more than one.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/policyschemes?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Comment: The token is successfully generated and only after while trying to connect to the server getting the error.

Comment: The issue is NOT TLS.  If TLS is bad then you would not get a token.  The issue could be a cookie that needs to be deleted.  What happened with PS debug?  Here is another debug page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/tshoot-connect-pass-through-authentication and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/cannot-connect-mailbox-pop-imap-outlook

Answer (score 0):

i guess it is because of the encryption when accessing imap. since 21.6.2023 microsoft has deactivated the support for starttls. since then access via imap is only possible using ssl/tls. officially startssl was also never supported for imap.

await client.ConnectAsync(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.**StartTls**);

maybe the use SslOnConnect instead of StartTls solves the problem

greetings
marco manngatter

Answer (score 0):

> since 21.6.2023 microsoft has deactivated the support for starttls

Can you please link the source where you found this